# ws:outbound-gateway custom interceptor with message header

Tags: web-services, spring-integration

I am using ws:outbound-gateway to invoke soap service. I have added interceptor as well.

```
   <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="wsOutboundGateway"
        request-channel="requestChannel" 
        uri="{soapURI}"
        message-sender="httpMessageSender"
        message-factory="messageFactory"
        interceptor="myInterceptor"
        marshaller="jaxbMarshaller" unmarshaller="jaxbMarshaller">
        <int-ws:uri-variable name="soapURI" expression="headers.soapURI"/>
    </int-ws:outbound-gateway>
```

myInterceptor is a class which implements ClientInterceptor.

Query: I have the information in message header which needs to be intercepted. Is there any way to receive the message header in the interceptor.

Note : I am setting the header value in thread local and getting back in the interceptor now.

Any better solution, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the premise and context.

Sorry, but you have to share more info. What is the header? What do you do with that? Maybe there is no need to intercept it in the `ClientInterceptor`, but would be better even before `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`?

**UPDATE**

> I have the info in message header where I have to pass it in the soap header.

Actually `ClientInterceptor` is fully for different purpose and its intention do not modify the message.

There is `WebServiceMessageCallback` abstraction for message modification before sending.

But having your requirements like pass SOAP header I can suggest you to take a look into out-of-the-box component like `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper`. Its `populateStandardHeaders` deal only with `SoapAction` and `populateUserDefinedHeader` populates only as `soapHeader.addAttribute()`. So, consider some extension of that class to insert custom tags into `soapHeader`. And already without any `ThreadLocal` hacks.

Comment: I have the info in message header where I have to pass it in the soap header.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..I will extend DefaultSoapHeaderMapper and pass the soap header.